# Weblogic's plan.xml not shown in admin console

Tags: weblogic, war

I read a lot about Weblogic ability to alter web.xml's  during deployment.

Functional, this works quite well: In my `web.xml` I have a bunch of env-entries:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>config/fileservice/outputCharacterSet</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

and in the `plan.mxl`:

```
<variable>
    <name>config/fileservice/outputCharacterSet</name>
    <value>UTF-8</value>
    <description>Specify the output character set to be used for dumping the JMS messages.
</variable>
```

and further down

```
<variable-assignment>
    <name>config/fileservice/outputCharacterSet</name>
    <xpath>/web-app/env-entry/[env-entry-name="config/fileservice/outputCharacterSet"]/env-entry-value</xpath>
    <operation>replace</operation>
</variable-assignment>
```

During deployment that works like a charm.

But no matter what I do, in Weblogics Admin Console this entries never appear:
Within the deployment (WAR) > Deployment plan > Tuning Paramter nothing is shown.

Even

```
<value xsi:nil="true"></value>
```

causes the application to just deploy - the value isn't set afterwards. But from the documentation [1] I would expect some kind of user dialog during deployment forcing the deployer to enter some sensible value.

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13702/export.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only meant for "tuning parametesr" and not for modifying the web.xml itself.
That's only possible via plan.xml

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the directory as below before the deployment

```
c:\my_app_root\plan\Plan.xml
c:\my_app_root\app\xyz.war
```

During the deployment, you should specifiy the c:\my_app_root as the path. As I understand, this is the recommended directory structure for deployment
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13702/config.htm

As to the null value issue you mentioned, the documentation says it applies to external resource only such as JDNI name of a data source. Did you try to make a JNDI value empty in your deployment descriptor AND your Plan.xml? Besides, WLS does not provide any user dialog during deployment to force the deployer to enter the right value. It simply fails the deployment. That's what the "force" means I am afraid. Of course, I would vote yes for such user dialog feature. :-)